# ¿Mi función está bien escrita?

Tags: c

Tengo dudas sobre funciones en C. Me gustaría saber si está bien escrita esta función, ya que no sé si debería tener carácter `void` o poner un carácter tipo `int` al declararla. ¡Muchas gracias!

```
void Pleno () {
    printf("felicitaciones!!");
    dinero_apostado = dinero_apostado * 35;
    dinero_jugador = dinero_jugador + dinero_apostado;
    dinero_mesa = dinero_mesa - dinero_apostado;
    printf(" Tu saldo de dinero es %i y el de la mesa es %i\n", dinero_jugador, dinero_mesa);
}
```

Comment: Si la función no devuelve nada `void` es lo correcto.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! no dupliques tu pregunta!!! y probaste este codigo???

Comment: Aparentemente está bien escrita, aunque falta bastante contexto. Quieres devolver algún valor? Las variables están definidas como globales? Las tendrías que pasar por parámetros?...

Comment: Yo suelo dejar menos espacios de *indentado* por la izquierda, y si pongo los textos en castellano suelo usar también los signos de inicio `¡` y `¿`.

Comment: Las funciones void son utilizadas cuando no hay que devolver ningun valor a ninguna  variable que sea local en otra funcion como por ejemplo main. Aun asi con lo poco que has mostrado no podemos saber que es lo que te propones, ni siquiera podemos saber como gestionas los valores  de las estructuras.

Te agradeceriamos que compartaras mas codigo y que fueras mas explicito a tus inquietudes y necesidades.

Answer (score 1):

> ¿Mi función está bien escrita?

Sí y No

Está bien escrita porque el compilador la acepta sin mostrar ningún error ni advertencia... es decir, lexicográficamente es correcta.

Peeeero a nivel funcional no es una función con la que a mi me gustaría tener que lidiar. El motivo es que usas **variables globales** sin necesidad. Las variables globales son una herramienta que es preferible evitar siempre que sea posible:

- Las variables globales pueden ser tanto consultadas como modificadas en cualquier parte del programa. Puede ser dificil recordar en qué sitios se usa y entonces es cuando el programa de repente se vuelve errático y no encontramos el motivo.
- Las variables globales pueden solaparse con variables locales con el mismo nombre

  ```
    int a = 0;

    void func1()
    {
      a++;
    }

    int func2()
    {
      int a = 10;
      a++;
    }

    int main()
    {
      func1();
      printf("%d", a);

      func2();
      printf("%d", a);
    }
  ```
- Los depuradores no van a mostrar las variables globales... tendremos que cargarlas a mano para conocer su valor.
- En entornos multihilo, las variables globales pueden ser un infierno

Así pues, para que tu función estuviese bien escrita debería adoptar hábitos saludables, entre los que se encuentra evitar el uso de variables globales en la medida de lo posible.

Si la declaración de tu función fuese así:

```
void Pleno(double * dinero_apostado, double * dinero_jugador, double * dinero_mesa)
```

Ya no parecería una función tan inofensiva. Dado que recibe tres valores vía puntero (y dado que dichos punteros no son constantes), es bastante probable que la función modifique esas variables en algún momento. A la hora de revisar el código o seguirle la pista a un error, este tipo de prácticas te pueden ahorrar muchos dolores de cabeza.